# Extra padding on header and footer image in email in Outlook

Tags: html, css, email

I am designing an email in Convio and for some reason the header and footer images have extra padding on the left and top/bottom (respectively) in Outlook 2010 and 2013. [Here is a screen cap of how it is rendering.](http://www.jhpiego.org/email-templates/2014-Holiday-Campaign/GivingTuesday/email-error.jpg) I've googled this and used tricks from Email on Acid and Litmus... etc. and for the life of me I can't figure out where the padding is coming from. Thought it would be helpful to maybe get another set of eyes on it. Hopefully it's something stupid that I am just missing. Thanks for the help.

Here is the code. Since it is built in Convio, there is no head or body tags because Convio does not support a full HTML email, just content within it's template.

Here is my CSS. It is mainly to help render the email correctly in Yahoo.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ExternalClass {width:100%;}
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;}
.ExternalClass img {line-height: 100%;}
body {-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none;}
body {margin:0; padding:0;}
table td {border-collapse:collapse;}
p {margin:0; padding:0; margin-bottom:0;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {color: black; line-height: 100%;}
a, a:link {color:#2ba6cb;text-decoration: underline;}      
span.yshortcuts { color:#000; background-color:none; border:none;}
span.yshortcuts:hover, span.yshortcuts:active, span.yshortcuts:focus {color:#000; background-color:none; border:none;}
a:visited { color: #005581; text-decoration: none} 
a:focus   { color: #005581; text-decoration: underline}  
a:hover   { color: #82a535; text-decoration: underline}
table {margin:0; padding:0;}
img {display:block; margin:0; padding:0;}
#cv-poweredBy {visibility: hidden;}
</style>
```

Here is my HTML.

```
<div align="center">
<!-- BLUE BACKGROUND -->
<table style="background-color: #005581; color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; table-layout: fixed; margin: 0 auto; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#005581">
<tr>
<td valign="top">

<!-- TOP LINKS -->
<center>
<table style="background: #005581; color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" align="center" bgcolor="#005581">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="font-size: 14px; padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 30px;" align="center">
  <a style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;" href="http://[[S29:DOMAIN]]/site/TellAFriend">Forward to a friend</a>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;" href="http://[[S29:DOMAIN]]/site/MessageViewer">View Web Version</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</center>
<!-- END TOP LINKS -->

<center>
<!-- WHITE BACKGROUND -->
<table style="background-color: #ffffff;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff;">
<tr>
<td width="600" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<a href="http://give.jhpiego.org/site/Donation2?df_id=1720&1720.donation=form1">
<img src="http://www.jhpiego.org/email-templates/2014-Holiday-Campaign/GivingTuesday/imgs/GivingTuesday-Header-rev.jpg" alt="Join the Fight Against Ebola This #GivingTuesday!" width="600" height="250" vspace="0" hspace="0" style="display:inline; padding:0; margin:0;" border="0"/>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px; color: #101010; text-align:left;" width="600">
<p style="padding: 20px">Dear Friends,<br><br>

As we celebrate <a href="http://give.jhpiego.org/site/Donation2?df_id=1720&1720.donation=form1" style="color: #99c525; font-weight:bold; text-decoration: none;">#GivingTuesday</a> today, we are honoring four courageous nurses who are working tirelessly to keep women and families safe from a highly infectious disease devastating West Africa. <strong>Marion Subah, Comfort Gebeh, Varwo Sirtor-Gbassie and Nyapu Taylor </strong> are members of the Jhpiego family.<br><br>

As the Ebola virus swept through their native Liberia, they went to work day after day, redoubling their efforts to ensure that health care providers on the frontlines had the specialized skills in infection prevention and control to work <a href="http://give.jhpiego.org/site/Donation2?df_id=1720&1720.donation=form1"><img style="float: right; padding: 10px;" src="http://www.jhpiego.org/email-templates/2014-Holiday-Campaign/GivingTuesday/imgs/GivingTuesday-CTA.jpg" alt="Help Stop The Ebola Epidemic! Donate Now" title="Help Stop The Ebola Epidemic! Donate Now" hspace="10" vspace="10" width="225" height="300" align="right" /></a>confidently and safely in health centers and hospitals. They also dedicated themselves to helping health facilities restore critically needed maternal and child health services so pregnant women and mothers do not die giving birth.<br><br>

These four women are respected colleagues, who, along with our dedicated staff in Ebola-impacted Guinea, are doing their utmost to prevent the needless deaths of women and their families in these countries. They embody <strong>Jhpiego's commitment to West Africa</strong>, where we have had a strong presence in both Liberia (14 years) and Guinea (21 years). Working successfully with the Ministries of Health and partners to strengthen health care systems and save lives, Jhpiego is on the ground, updating the skills of nurses and midwives so they can continue to provide quality care to vulnerable women and babies during this emergency.<br><br>

On this #GivingTuesday, as we focus on what makes <strong>Jhpiego</strong> unique, I invite you to be part of this global effort to save lives and help Marion, Comfort, Nyapu and Varwo in their prevention work.  <a style="font-weight: bold; color: #99c525; text-decoration: none;" href="http://give.jhpiego.org/site/Donation2?df_id=1720&1720.donation=form1">With your support, we can do even more beyond #GivingTuesday! Please help us contain this epidemic by investing in Jhpiego's work.</a> Thank you in advance for your serious consideration of this special request.</p>

<center>
<table style="background: #ffffff;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="400">
<tr>
<td width="130">
<img src="http://www.jhpiego.org/email-templates/2014-Fundraising-Emails/DayofGirl-LesliePhoto.jpg" alt="Photo of Leslie Mancuso" width="120" height="120" style="display:inline; padding-right: 20px;" />
</td>
<td width="270" font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height:22px; color: #101010; text-align:left;"">
<img src="http://www.jhpiego.org/email-templates/2014-Fundraising-Emails/Leslie-Signature.gif" alt="Leslie Mancuso's Signature" width="200" style="display:inline; padding:0; margin:0;" border="0" /><br />
Leslie Mancuso, PhD, RH, FAAN<br />
President and Chief Executive Officer
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>

<br>

</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="600" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<a href="http://give.jhpiego.org/site/Donation2?df_id=1720&1720.donation=form1">
<img src="http://www.jhpiego.org/email-templates/2014-Holiday-Campaign/GivingTuesday/imgs/GivingTuesday-Footer.jpg" alt="Marion Subah, Comfort Gebeh, Nyapu Taylor and Varwo Sirtor-Gbassie" width="600" height="200" vspace="0" hspace="0" style="display:inline; padding:0; margin:0;" />
</a>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
<!-- END WHITE BACKGROUND -->
</center>

<!-- FOOTER -->
<center>
<table style="background: #005581; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" border="0"         cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" align="center" bgcolor="#005581">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #005581; color: #fff; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; text-align:left; padding-right:50px; padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:100px; width:376px" width="376">
You are receiving this email because you have made a donation to Jhpiego in the past.<br><br>
We hate to see you go, but you can
<a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: underline;" href="http://[[S29:DOMAIN]]/site/CO">unsubscribe</a> if you no longer want to receive these messages.
<br /><br />
<strong>Don't forget to connect with us on:</strong><br /><br />
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/Jhpiego"><img style="display: inline;" title="Facebook" src="http://give.jhpiego.org/images/content/pagebuilder/alumni-facebook.png" border="0" alt="Facebook" /></a>&nbsp;
<a href="https://twitter.com/jhpiego"><img style="display: inline;" title="Twitter" src="http://give.jhpiego.org/images/content/pagebuilder/alumni-twitter.png" border="0" alt="Twitter" /></a>
</td>
<td style="background-color: #005581; color: #fff; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; text-align:right; padding-top:25px; width:174px" width="174" valign="top">
<a href="http://www.jhpiego.org"><img src="http://give.jhpiego.org/images/content/pagebuilder/Jhpiego_logo_wh_PMS.png" border="0" alt="Visit Jhpiego's Website" width="174" height="73"/></a><br><br>
1615 Thames Street<br />
Baltimore, MD 21231<br />
410-537-1800
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<center>
<!-- END FOOTER -->

</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- END BLUE BACKGROUND -->

</div>
```

Comment: Outlook uses the Word2007 HTML engine. Don't rely on CSS at all.

Comment: You should also use HTML 4.01 Strict.

Comment: Can you tell me actually where the problem is in my code? Your comments don't really help me. I updated the code so you can see what I actually use in Convio. I don't actually have a choice in the DocType because of the way Convio works.

Comment: [This](http://jonathanaquino.com/outlook-html-email-validator.php) tool can help you on validating your code for Outlook.